# Dynamically Creating Json Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chart.js and in order to generate charts, the data loaded in seems to be in Json format. For example

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]};
```

I am trying to create a variable similar to the example above by using data from a Json response...
The Json response is formated as:

```
{
"points": {
"0": {
  "data_in": 8606441,
  "data_out": 25531384,
  "num_request": 2712,
  "time": "Fri, 10 Jul 2015 00:00:00 GMT"
},
 "1": {
  "data_in": 1719403,
  "data_out": 3463972,
  "num_request": 1446,
  "time": "Fri, 10 Jul 2015 01:00:00 GMT"
 },
 "2": {
  "data_in": 284120,
  "data_out": 3244090,
  "num_request": 786,
   "time": "Fri, 10 Jul 2015 02:00:00 GMT"
 },
```

I am trying to populate a variable called temp to match the Chart.js format.

```
   var temp = {
   labels: [],
   dataset: [
    {
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: []
  }
  ]
 };



    $.getJSON('/api/time_points', data, function(data){
    $.each(data.points, function( index, value ){
        temp.labels.push(data.points[index].time);
        temp.dataset[data].push(data.points[index].num_request);
    });

});
```

This does not seem to be working however. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

temp.dataset is an array, and you are trying to use data, an object, as an index.

It should be something like:

```
temp.dataset[0].push(data.points[index].num_request);
```

(or whatever the index should be) not:

```
temp.dataset[data].push(data.points[index].num_request);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That actually helped me catch a crucial error. 
I think the right code is: temp["dataset"][0]["data"].push(data.points[index].num_request);

Comment: But the chart is still not generating...hmmm